# Airflow: transfer a huge dataset from a database to a remote machine

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I have the following setup: Remote machine 'D' contains Postgres DB. Remote machine 'C' contains a data processing platform. Airflow is running on Local machine 'L'. It is expected that simple select queries from the DB will result in a dataset of size around 1 GB.

I want to create an airflow DAG with one of the tasks that runs a query on the DB and transfers the result onto 'C'. But the official documentation of GenericTransfer operator says:

"This is mean to be used on small-ish datasets that fit in memory."

How can I reliably transfer a huge dataset from 'D' to 'C'?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Operator with dbapi's executemany to insert datas

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using postgres, why not use COPY?

It is one of the best parts of PG. It is fast both in and out and works for larger datasets.

[Here is a link to the COPY command docs.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try loop block in python which can generates and executes queries with limited data.

limit = 256

loop {

```
  query (with limit)<b>
   limit +=256

 }
```